# open NUnit.Framework - the namespace or module is not defined. Referencing in F#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, f#, nunit, nuget

I am using `VS2013 Professional`, `F#`, `C#` and `Nunit`. It is worth noting that this is my first attempt with `F#` so question is most likely stupid and solution is obvious.

What I am trying to do is implement test cases using `NUnit` and use `TestCaseSource` attribute with `TestCaseData`.

Test:

```ml
namespace Legal.Tests.Helpers
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Text
open System.Threading.Tasks
open NUnit.Framework
open Legal.Website.Infrastructure

type FTest() = 
    [<TestFixture>]
    [<TestCaseSource("FTestData")>]
    let ConcatTest(text : string, expected : string) =
    [<Test>]
        let actual = Saga.Services.Legal.Website.Infrastructure.FunctionModule.TestFunction text
        Assert.AreEqual expected actual
    let FTestData : seq<TestCaseData> = [ new TestCaseData (text = "x", expected = "Item1xItem2" ); new TestCaseData (text = "y", expected = "Item1yItem2" ) ]
```

Function tested:

```ml
namespace Legal.Website.Infrastructure

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Web

type Test(text2 : string) = 
  member this.Text = "Item1"
  member this.Text2 = text2

module functions = 
    let TestFunction (text : string) =
        let test = new Test (text2 = "Item2")
        String.Concat [test.Text; text; test.Text2]
```

One thing worth noting - I have created `F#` test file and file with function by renaming `.cs` file to `.fs`.

**Problem:** when I try to `open` any library that is not `System` (in this case Nuget package `NUnit.Framework` and Referenced project `Legal.Website.Infrastructure`) I get error: `the namespace or module is not defined` both are referenced in Test Project and `.cs` tests in same directory run fine.

Comment: Not sure I understand but - I don't think you can just rename `.cs` file to an `.fs` file - you need to create a new F# project for this.

Comment: @TomasPetricek so I cannot have .fs files in C# project like for example .vb files.

Comment: @TomasPetricek could you please post your comment as an answer so I could accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer explains the problem better :-) Feel free to accept that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is stupid.

`.fs` files cannot be added to C# project like for example `.vb` files. To do this properly one needs to add F# project to solution, see screenshot below.

[image]

Implementation:

```
module Implementation

let Concat(text:string) = 
    "root"+ text
```

Test:

```
module Test
open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type Test() = 
    member this.ConcatinationTestData() = 
        [new TestCaseData("roottext","text"); new TestCaseData("root","")]
    [<Test>]
    [<TestCaseSource("ConcatinationTestData")>]
    static member ConcatinationTest(expected:string, text:string) =
       Assert.AreEqual(expected,Implementation.Concat(text))
       |> ignore
```

Debug -> Attach to process -> nunit-agent.exe

Result:
[image]